# Difference between setinterval with an exist function and lambda expression for class in js

Tags: javascript, function, oop, setinterval, bullet

I'm making a simple game with javascript that you can fire bullet to enemies.
Actually I don't have any problem making it but:

I made a class for my bullets that it has a *Move* function and I want to set an interval for it
but when I set an interval in my constructor like this:

```
    setInterval(this.Move, 0);
```

I see this error:

*uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
at Move (game.js:152)*

But when I set and inverval like this:

```
    setInterval(() => {
        this.Move();
    }, 0);
```

It works without any problem.

I just what to know what is wrong with first one, I think the second way, you're making an extra thing (lambda expression).

Bullet Class: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q23Lk.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good question. The key difference is the use of the arrow function. Arrow functions are designed to bind to the scope that they are defined in.

By simply passing `this.Move` to `setInterval`, `setInterval` will invoke the function without binding to the class/instance scope.

The code below demonstrates several ways you could have passed `this.Move` to `setInterval`. Some have the correct scope, some don't, hopefully this will help your understanding.

```js
let outside_function = undefined;

class X {

    constructor() {
        this.message = 'moving'

        // function is not bound to instance
        setInterval(this.move, 1000); // undefined

        // function is bound to instance
        setInterval(this.move.bind(this), 1000) // 'moving'

        // arrow function binds to 'this'
        setInterval(() => this.move(), 1000) // 'moving'

        // outside_function has no relationship with the class
        outside_function = this.move;
        setInterval(outside_function, 1000); // undefined
        setInterval(outside_function.bind(this), 1000) // 'moving'
    }

    move() {
        console.log(this.message)
    }
}

// also note that we can call the function like this
// again, no class instance here
X.prototype.move() // undefined

new X();
```